# Rendering image with an effect

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, glsl, hlsl

I am drawing images on a canvas. If I draw the image without any effects, it renders fine. If I add a custom Hue effects I get some strange results when I render the canvas. Im am not sure if the problem is from my shader, or if its the way I am rendering it.

[image]

On the bottom is without the effect. And on the top is with the effect.

Here is the HLSL shader:

```
float HueDegree : register(C0);

sampler2D Samp : register(S0);

float3x3 QuaternionToMatrix(float4 quat)
{
    float3 cross = quat.yzx * quat.zxy;
    float3 square = quat.xyz * quat.xyz;
    float3 wimag = quat.w * quat.xyz;

    square = square.xyz + square.yzx;

    float3 diag = 0.5 - square;
    float3 a = (cross + wimag);
    float3 b = (cross - wimag);

    return float3x3(
    2.0 * float3(diag.x, b.z, a.y),
    2.0 * float3(a.z, diag.y, b.x),
    2.0 * float3(b.y, a.x, diag.z));
}

static const float3 lumCoeff = float3(0.2125, 0.7154, 0.0721);

float4 main(float2 uv : TEXCOORD) : COLOR
{
    float4 outputColor = tex2D(Samp, uv.xy);
    outputColor.rgb /= outputColor.a;

    float3 root3 = float3(0.57735, 0.57735, 0.57735);
    float half_angle = 0.5 * radians(HueDegree); // 0 to 360 degree
    float4 rot_quat = float4((root3 * sin(half_angle)), cos(half_angle));
    float3x3 rot_Matrix = QuaternionToMatrix(rot_quat);

    outputColor.rgb = mul(rot_Matrix, outputColor.rgb);

    outputColor.rgb *= outputColor.a;

    return outputColor;
}
```

And here is how I am rendering it:

```
Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, tmpCanvas.Width, tmpCanvas.Height);

RenderTargetBitmap rtb = new RenderTargetBitmap((int)rect.Right,
(int)rect.Bottom, 96d, 96d, System.Windows.Media.PixelFormats.Default);
rtb.Render(tmpCanvas);
```

If I draw the images with the effects on the canvas it looks fine. Only until I render the canvas do the problems arise. I have rendered all my visuals like this, I have other custom effects and they work fine. I cant figure it out. If I remove

```
outputColor.rgb /= outputColor.a;
...
outputColor.rgb *= outputColor.a;
```

from the shader, then I dont get that white background problem, but I still get that jagged edges.

Comment: I didn't realize this was C#...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
rect.Effect = new BlurEffect() { Radius = 0 };
rect.Effect.BeginAnimation(BlurEffect.RadiusProperty, new DoubleAnimation(5, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500)));
rect.Effect.BeginAnimation(BlurEffect.RadiusProperty, new DoubleAnimation(0, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500)));
```